# Tensorflow-GPU not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I would like to train a model using an Amazon EC2 instance. To do so I selected the AWS Deep Learning Base AMI GPU CUDA 11 whose id is ami-00d0a61a0238cae2e and is described as "Built with NVIDIA CUDA, cuDNN, NCCL, GPU Driver, Docker, NVIDIA-Docker and EFA support." The instance type I selected is p2.xlarge.
Upon connecting to the instance I discovered that Tensorflow is not installed, I thus followed the instructions from [the official installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and everything went smooth. Unfortunately when I try to list the available GPU devices I get an empty list.

```
(tf) ubuntu@ip-172-31-57-243:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2022-12-05 08:52:49.561778: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-12-05 08:52:50.840367: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/amazon/efa/lib:/opt/amazon/openmpi/lib:/usr/local/cuda/efa/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2022-12-05 08:52:50.840525: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/amazon/efa/lib:/opt/amazon/openmpi/lib:/usr/local/cuda/efa/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/
2022-12-05 08:52:50.840572: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2022-12-05 08:52:53.890292: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:267] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-12-05 08:52:53.890369: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (ip-172-31-57-243): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
[]
```

How do I fix this? Is there a way to use tensorflow-gpu on Amazon EC2 instances?

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia drivers installed properly? From the error message it seems not

Comment: It was my initial thought too but when I tried installing the drivers it told me that they were already installed.

Comment: Maybe they are installed, but not loaded, the message is very clear, you need to fix that before continuing. Or maybe you do not have a Nvidia GPU, in this case the drivers would not load.